# How can I pass extra data to  fragment class and how to get that data in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have developed an application with tab using FragmentActivity. How can I pass some extra data while calling fragments and how can I get that data in fragment class?

The code for adding tab is given below. Fragment class is specified directly within it.

```
mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
    DetailFragment.class, null);
```

In this case how can I pass some data to fragment class. Please any one help to do this.

Comment: you pass extra in FragmnetActivity or in Fragment class?

Comment: how can I get extra data in Fragment class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Pass data(extras) to a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

In that example they show how to use the FragmentTabs with the support package, if you look down you can see that they implement their own TabManager class. There they implement the function addTab:

```
     public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        mTabs.put(tag, info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
```

There you create the object TabInfo, previously defined as:

```
    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }
```

you can put data on that bundle (args). Now if you look at the overridden function onTabChanged you can see how the bundle is passed on the instantiation of the fragment(newTab.args):

```
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }
```

Finally you can access that bundle from the fragment itself calling getArguments ()

hope that helps.

Comment: :) good to hear, could you mark the answer as valid then? so people see this question as resolved.